# Replacing Ubuntu 16.04 with Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, system-installation, kubuntu, kde

I have a dual boot system with Windows on sda and Ubuntu 16.04 on sdb.  I would like to install kubuntu 16.04 over the ubuntu.  I have burned the Kubuntu Live CD.  When I asked to install, it did not allow me to select the disk I wanted to install to, nor did it offer me a replacement option.  My only choice was to install on sda.  I don't want to do that.  I want to put it over Ubuntu on sdb, although ideally I'd like to put it on sdc which is empty.  Ubuntu gives me that option in the installer but Kubuntu doesn't.

I have no idea what I am doing with this computer or Linux, so any instructions will need to be very basic.

I have seen a suggestion to just install the Plasma desktop and KDE packages that I want.   But I have no idea what KDE packages I want, since I'm new to all this.  I have tried the Live CD, and like the environment a great deal more than Unity, and KDE has some software that I really want that won't work right in Ubuntu --KAlarm and their PIM software.

Comment: You should just be able to install Kubuntu from the command like by typing in `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: If you don't do a clean install of Kubuntu, you'll end up with something that's neither fish nor fowl. I suggest you figure out a way to do a clean install. Maybe people over at https://kubuntuforums.net can help.